# Are there PHP tools to generate CRUD screens from DB schema?

Tags: php, database, crud

I've been using [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/) to quickly generate CRUD screens for databases; it's a quick way to start interacting with data in my projects (and lets me toss together internal admin pages fast)... but it doesn't read the DB schema, so I have to manually set it up.

I'm looking for a tool/way to quickly generate CRUD from beginning to end: I give it a DB table, and it reads the schema, generates the HTML markup for the form, and does the CRUD work on the db itself.

Does this exist? My goal is to have zero setup for basic functionality, and then I'd love the option of being able to extend that basic setup to further refine the experience. (For example: if it can see my database table has four varchar() fields, that would be ready to go with four editing fields "out of the box," but then I'd like to be able to add a little bit of code/set some flags to specify the one varchar() column that is meant to hold an email address, so the tool would then do data validation to only allow emails in that field.)

UPDATE: I'm seeking a solution that I can drop into my existing PHP project(s) -- not an entire framework.

Comment: closed as not constructive question but still I have an interesting site I found about this topic: http://www.phpscaffold.com/ It lets you easily generate CRUD files from an sql table export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for a drop-in admin like this too, here's one I found so far:

http://ajaxcrud.com/

Answer (score 4):

[The Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) Does this out of the box.  You use a web gui to plug in the database table name and it generates crud screens and active record classes along with all the models, views, and controllers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually not looking for a framework (and I updated my question to reflect that after you helped me realize I didn't specify that), but Yii looks cool. I'm going to play with it for another project.

Comment: Oh, well at least we made the question stronger.

Answer (score 2):

Try Grocery CRUD: http://www.grocerycrud.com/

It's based on [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and is quick to setup basic CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

I think just about anything you might be interested in will require some front-end configuration or parameter setting.

One tool that I've heard of is [TTswiftcoder - v2.6](http://www.turningturnip.co.uk/free-mysql-php-generator/).  One of it's nice features is its cost ($0.00).

I think there are plenty of tools around - both free and not-so-free.  Try googling phrases like PHP Crud, PHP data grid, PHP code generator and the like.  Also try Sourceforge, Freshmeat, [phpclasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/), Codango , ...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CoughPHP? https://github.com/awbush/coughphp

> Cough generates all the code you need
>   for managing the object
>   model-to-relational model mapping.
>   This includes simple methods for all
>   your CRUD functionality. This also
>   includes Cough Collection classes that
>   represent the relationships between
>   tables in your data model.

and: http://www.coughphp.com/docs/1.1/data_validation/

Comment: It doesn't look like Cough actually generates the interface (form, input fields, etc), though it appears to handle everything else.